# Unresolved bundle when installing Vega

Tags: installation, vega, kali-linux

I am running the latest kali linux (gnome) and im trying to install Vega but whenever I try opening it the loading screen show up for a second then a pop up shows up and says `An error has occurred. See the log file /home/*myuser*/Downloads/vega/configuration/1606421537381.log.` and also says in the terminal where i run it from `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/home/*myuser*/Downloads/vega/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.0.v20120529-1548.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release`. So then I do the most reasonable things and read the log.

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.9.1
java.vendor=Debian
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.139
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.300.v20110815-1744 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.144
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.300.v20110815-1744.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.154
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.154
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.300.v20110815-1744.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.154
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.156
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.156
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.300.v20110815-1744 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.156
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-11-26 14:58:11.157
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I assume that ive not installed something but Im not sure what I can do about it

Answer (score 2):

use jdk 8 it resolved the issue for me. After you try this one
[https://github.com/subgraph/Vega/issues/188][1] as mentioned.

check your `java -version` as it seems to be 11.0.9.1.
downgrade both java and javac version using first install ver 8

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

then select from alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

as well as java one

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

check the versions again with java -version and javac -version.

Now try Vega

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue.

This script solved my issue

[https://github.com/subgraph/Vega/issues/188][1]